# How to find out what a cluster represents on a PCA biplot?

Tags: python-3.x, cluster-analysis, k-means, pca

I am building a K means algorithm and have multiple variables to feed into it. As of this I am using PCA to transform the data to two dimensions. When I display the PCA biplot I don't understand what similarities the data has to be grouped into a specific cluster. I am using a customer segmentation dataset. I.E: I want to be able to know that a specific cluster is a cluster as a customer has a low income but spends a lot of money on products.

Comment: If your last sentence describes what you are trying to do, I do not understand why you would use PCA.  Instead, plot income vs amount spent.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using k-means:

Compute the mean of each cluster on the *original* data. Now you can compare these attributes.

Alternatively: don't use PCA in the first place, if it had your analysis... k-means is as good as PCA at coping with several dozen variables.

Comment: How would i compute the mean of each cluster on the original data?

Comment: As well how would I display my multidimensional data on a graph? I am using PCA to reduce the dimension of data so I can then display it

Comment: The arithmetic mean is computed exactly as always. That is basically linear algebra. You can visualize multidimensional data for example using a scatterplot matrix.